# How to customize the appearance of datestamp in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Please check this website: http://vabbie.com/

The website is in Wordpress. The datestamp at the left side of post is very generic looking. I want to convert it into the following style:

[image]

The numeric part is big and indendted on the left side. The "October" part is OCT and year 2012 below it.

I am using the following php code for datestamp:

```
<div id="time"><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></div>
```

But I am not sure how to style it.

Anyone with Wordpress knowledge help please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the same format that the PHP date function uses:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Check out the format table and choose the appropriate characters to get the desired output as documented.

```
echo '<div id="time"><span>' . the_time('j') . '</span><span>' . the_time('M') . '<br />' . the_time('Y') . '</span></div>';
```

To start you off =o) just style the SPAN so one floats to the side and then style the font etc all with CSS.

Comment: Thanks :) But how do I style the individual elements in the PHP code like Month, Date and Day separately (like using <span> ? ) I have no idea how to use html with PHP codes... Just want to make these 3 elements have different style

Comment: see edit, I got you half-way, you just need to add the appropriate CSS.

Comment: Ok I used this: <?php
    echo "<div id="time"><span>" . the_time('j') . '</span><span>' . the_time('M') . '<br />' . the_time('Y') . '</span></div>';
    ?> but it gives error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: sorry I had noticed the typo, and had fixed it in my post, you copied it before I did. Just use current edit.

Comment: Thanks cryptic :) It worked but with a minor customization to code you gave: 

<div id="time">
<span class="day"><?php the_time('j') ?></span>
<span class="month"><?php the_time('F') ?></span>
<span class="year"><?php the_time('Y') ?></span>
 </div>

With the CSS now I could do the rest and it worked like charm! :) Thank you for that bit of code

Answer (score 3):

here is the code, along with CSS

```
<style>
.post-date {
    float:left;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin:5px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.post-monthyear {
    float:left;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height:12px;
    color: #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
</style>    
<div class="post-date"> <?php echo the_time('j') ?> </div>
<div class="post-monthyear"><?php echo the_time('M') ?> <br/><?php echo the_time('Y') ?> </div>
```

Around the  tag is the CSS, you can include on the index.php or you can paste to the css file. just play with the CSS for styling..

Hope it help..